# Angular2 component render profiling

Tags: performance, angular, components, profiling

Is there any way to profile angualar2 component rendering time separating it from service call. I know chrome dev tools profiling gives time at the function level. I want something that gives insights in to angular2 components

Answer (score 1):

> Try to have a look at

[@angular/benchpress](https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/master/modules/%40angular/benchpress)

> I think it's what are you looking for.